# How can i sort array by value of array

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have given array below i want to sort that array by **Level** value 1 to 4.

**Form :**

```
Array ( [20] => Array ( [sid] => 1020 [L] => 1027 [R] => 1033 [Level] => 1 ) 
    [27] => Array ( [sid] => 1027 [L] => 1030 [R] => 1073 [Level] => 2 )
    [30] => Array ( [sid] => 1030 [L] => 1074 [R] => [Level] => 3 ) 
    [74] => Array ( [sid] => 1074 [L] => [R] => [Level] => 4 ) 
    [73] => Array ( [sid] => 1073 [L] => [R] => [Level] => 3 ) 
    [33] => Array ( [sid] => 1033 [L] => [R] => [Level] => 2 ) )
```

**To:**

```
Array ( [20] => Array ( [sid] => 1020 [L] => 1027 [R] => 1033 [Level] => 1 ) 
    [27] => Array ( [sid] => 1027 [L] => 1030 [R] => 1073 [Level] => 2 )
    [33] => Array ( [sid] => 1033 [L] => [R] => [Level] => 2 )
    [30] => Array ( [sid] => 1030 [L] => 1074 [R] => [Level] => 3 ) 
    [73] => Array ( [sid] => 1073 [L] => [R] => [Level] => 3 ) 
    [74] => Array ( [sid] => 1074 [L] => [R] => [Level] => 4 )      
    )
```

Comment: How is this not just sorting on Level?  How is any "specific value" involved?

Comment: Or a simpler way: usort($arraytosort,array($this, 'Level'));

Answer (score 2):

You could use [array_multisort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

```
<?php
$array = array(
    array('Level'=>1),
    array('Level'=>2),
    array('Level'=>3),
    array('Level'=>4),
    array('Level'=>3),
    array('Level'=>2)
);

$tmp = array();
foreach($array as $r){
    $tmp[] = $r['Level'];
}

array_multisort($tmp,SORT_ASC,$array);

echo '<pre>',print_r($array),'</pre>';
```